# light, flexible and resizable 2 column layout (plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

i trying find something like jsfiddle.net resizable layout, but lightweight.
i found

- http://www.jquery-css.com/download-css-jquery-templates
- http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Please Recommend something

Comment: what do you want us to recommend? I prefer the second...

Comment: Where will be the best place to ask these kind of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php). See Layout -> Layout on panel.